# Is there a default NodePort when you deploy a service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have been following this guide:
https://medium.com/javarevisited/kubernetes-step-by-step-with-spring-boot-docker-gke-35e9481f6d5f

Which has the following line:

```
   kubectl expose deployment userapi --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080
```

I can access this service by just going to its external IP without specifying the nodeport. I am not sure why this is. I thought I would need to do externalip:nodeport.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick answer:

If you create a service of type `LoadBalancer` it will create all the resources needed by the `Nodeport` as well. It does not create the actual service, it simply implement all the features needed.

You can think to the types of services as a hierarchy, each time it adds a new functionality, but you need the previous one.

---

#### Explanation:

Quoting from official documentation:

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

If you create or expose a Noteport it will be assigned as well a ClusterIp.

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :

Just for the sake of completeness when creating a service a new resource of type endpoint is created as well that is totally managed by Kubernetes and should not be manually modified:

> ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType

Endpoints:

> Endpoints is a collection of endpoints that implement the actual service.
>        Example: Name: "mysvc", Subsets: [ { Addresses: [{"ip": "10.10.1.1"},
>        {"ip": "10.10.2.2"}], Ports: [{"name": "a", "port": 8675}, {"name": "b",
>        "port": 309}] }, { Addresses: [{"ip": "10.10.3.3"}], Ports: [{"name": "a",
>        "port": 93}, {"name": "b", "port": 76}] }, ]

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes services are hierarchical. A nodePort service will contain a clusterIP service. A loadBalancer service will contain a nodePort service.

If you execute your command `kubectl expose deployment userapi --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080` Kubernetes will create a service named `userapi`. Now in order to see the full (generated) yaml for this service simply do: `kubectl get svc userapi -o yaml`. You will see that Kubernetes automatically asigned a nodePort to your type:loadBalancer service.

> `NodePort`: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A `ClusterIP` Service, to which the `NodePort` Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the `NodePort` Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
>
> `LoadBalancer`: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.